# Is it necessary to inject $scope to a controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, scope, controller

Is there any difference between the following two code snippet? Both work.

1.

```
myApp.controller("myAppController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
// function body
}]);
```

2.

```
myApp.controller("myAppController", function($scope) {
// function body
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, difference will create during minfication. If you don't follow the step1 , minification will break your code.

Uglify Version of your 1st code

```
myApp.controller("myAppController",["$scope",function(o){}])
```

Uglify Version of your 2nd code

```
myApp.controller("myAppController",function(o){})
```

If you follow step 1 , Angular will find definition of `o` from injection.

But if you follow step 2 , Angular won't find definition of `o` from any source.